# How can i join multiple dataframes from a list to one dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can i join multiple dataframes from a list to one dataframe.

```
split_dataframes = split_dataframe(df, 10)
```

I have 10 smaller data frames that are in a list. One data frame looks like this:

```
    acceleration    seconds
count   47513.000000    47513.000000
mean    11098.667123    0.500126
std 777.451459  0.288757
min 4110.000000 0.000000
25% 10568.000000    0.250063
50% 11094.000000    0.500126
75% 11612.000000    0.750189
max 14244.000000    1.000253
```

but i want that the cells are all in one row. And then join the rows of all smaller dataframes to one last dataframe.

I tried this:

```
for i in split_dataframes:
    df1 = i.unstack()
    df1.index = [' '.join(x) for x in df1.index.values]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1).T
```

but it says:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Sophia. T\Downloads\Ordner\data_exp.ipynb Cell 4' in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in split_dataframes:
      2     df1 = i.unstack()
----> 3     df1.index = [' '.join(x) for x in df1.index.values]
      4     df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1).T
      5     df1 = pd.concat(df1, axis=0)

c:\Users\Sophia. T\Downloads\Ordner\data_exp.ipynb Cell 4' in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 for i in split_dataframes:
      2     df1 = i.unstack()
----> 3     df1.index = [' '.join(x) for x in df1.index.values]
      4     df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1).T
      5     df1 = pd.concat(df1, axis=0)

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: You have similar names for the function and what you describe as the list of dataframes.  Instead of `for i in split_dataframe:` you probably meant to write `for i in split_dataframes:`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AlexK, that does not work either :(

Comment: @Community, alright is it now clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this:

```
for i in split_dataframes:
    v = i.unstack().to_frame().T
    v.columns = v.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
    df1 = pd.concat([v], axis=1)
df1
```

But it ouputs a dataframe of 1 rows × 142539 columns